# How to create new string array conditionally with LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a string array like the following:

```
string[] myStrings = new string[] {"P1111111F","N1111110","Z2","P1111111F","Z1111110"};
```

How can I use LINQ to check each string is length = 8 and ends with "0" to get the following:

```
result: {"N","Y","N","N","Y"};
```

myStrings could be much longer with repeating strings so I'd like to achieve a solution that doesn't reprocess strings its already considered once.

Comment: string[] results = myStrings.Select(x => ((x.Length == 8) & x.EndsWith("0")) ? "Yes" : "No").ToArray();

Comment: Can you write a function that does so for a *single* string?  If you can, do so and show us the code; if you cannot, then you should ask a question about how to do the task for one string before you ask how to extend it to many strings.

Comment: @jdweng: Please don't post answers as comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The straightforward way:

```
string[] results = myStrings
    .Select(s => s?.Length == 8 && s.EndsWith("0") ? "Y" : "N")
    .ToArray();
```

The micro optimized way avoiding doubling algorithm of `ToArray`:

```
string[] results = new string[myStrings.Length];
for(int i = 0; i < myStrings.Length; i++)
{
    string s = myStrings[i];
    results[i] = s?.Length == 8 && s.EndsWith("0") ? "Y" : "N"; 
}
```

> `myStrings` could be much longer with repeating strings so I'd like to
> achieve a solution that doesn't reprocess strings its already
> considered once.

I don't think that caching those results for example in a `Dictionary<string, string>` would help at all. The check if so easy and fast that any lookup would be less efficient. You'd just waste memory.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Select is already special cased to return an enumerator that recognizes countable collections and that ToArray in turn is special cased as well. So you don't actually end up with the doubling algorithm... At least on new enough versions of .NET